# Microsoft-Graph API Determine whos the creator of an event

Tags: java, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I'm programming an application that integrates with Microsoft Graph API, we use strictly the Calendar Part, We have a shared outlook calendar with the whole team and everybody creates events there. My problem is that I need to get the creator of the event.

[According to the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) the *organizer* property should shows the type as [**recipient**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/recipient) and the value as **The organizer of the event**, I understand that this means the creator but apparently all calendar's entries shows the same *organizer* - the calendar's owner -. Even if I look to the property *isOrganizer*, it shows always true.

```
{
   "subject":"New Event 3",
   "isOrganizer":true,
   "organizer":{
      "emailAddress":{
         "name":"Owner",
         "address":"owner@..."
      }
   }
},
{
   "subject":"New event 2",
   "isOrganizer":true,
   "organizer":{
      "emailAddress":{
         "name":"Owner",
         "address":"owner@..."
      }
   }
},
{
   "subject":"New event",
   "isOrganizer":true,
   "organizer":{
      "emailAddress":{
         "name":"Owner",
         "address":"owner@..."
      }
   }
}
```

Does anybody has any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: _"...everybody creates events there..."_ but you mean everybody using its own account or using an unique account?

Comment: Everbody using its own account. It's a corporate group, I don't know if it does any difference but the all the users are different.

Answer (score 0):

What is the api you are using? Are you sure you are not filtering with the organizer? The documentation is correct, the Organizer object should correctly show who is the creator of the event; it shouldn't be related to the calendar owner. Please try the following api which will return all the events for this month and see if you have the same problem:

```
.../calendarview?startDateTime=2017-10-01T00:00:00Z&endDateTime=2017-10-31T23:59:59Z&$top=1000
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am doing. I'm using the 1.0 API. The only way I found to get the creator's name is when the event is created, the creator should put him/herself as an atendee so I can get by this property instead of organizer but I really don't like this solution :(

Comment: @ThiagoCarneiro This sounds like a Calendar setting issue. If you open the same event in Outlook Application Calendar, does it show the correct organizer? I don't think it is the api call issue. Would you please confirm that?

Comment: I think this is really an issue. Either the Outlook Application calendar or API return the same organizer. I tried to create different calendars with different users and non of them works as expected